# The variable that is going to enter the basis with revised Simplex already is in it

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-optimization

I am looking to solve the following program using the revised Simplex method :
$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}
\max \ & x_1&+ x_2\\
&x_1&-x_2&\le 1\\
&-2x_1&-x_2&\le -2\\
&-2x_1&+x_2&\le 2\\
\forall i, x_i
\end{aligned}
\end{cases}
$$
**Yet, I have a problem, the variable that is going to enter the matrix already is in it!**

It all started with the following basis for the first iteration : $J_0=\{x_2;x_3;x_5\}$. I already did an iteration that didn't offered any difficulty and led me to the following bases $J_1=\{x_2;x_4;x_5\}$. It also provided me $\hat{A_4}$ and $\hat b$:

\begin{align*}
\hat{A_{4}}&=(A^{J_0})^{-1}A^4\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0\\
1 & -1 &0\\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 1\\ 0
\end{pmatrix}\\
\hat{A_{4}}&=\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\-1\\1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

And naturally $\hat b_4=\begin{pmatrix}1\\-2\\2\end{pmatrix}$

Then I follow up with **Iteration 1:** as far as I took the minimum $>0$ between $\hat A_2/b=-1,\hat A_3/b=1/2,\hat A_5/b=1/2$, taking therfore $x_3$.

I first have

$$(A^{J_1})^{-1}=D_1(A^{J_0})^{-1}$$

Then I calculate the change of basis matrix :
$$D_1=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

Therfore

\begin{align}(A^{J_1})^{-1}&=
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 & 0\\
1 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\\
(A^{J_1})^{-1}&=\begin{pmatrix}1 &-2 &0\\
-1 & 1 & 0\\
2 & -1 & 1\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Then I calculated 
\begin{align}\Pi&=c(A^{J_1})^{-1}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1 &-2 &0\\
-1 & 1 & 0\\
2 & -1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\\
\Pi&=\begin{pmatrix}1 & -2 & 0\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

It allows me to calculate the new $\hat c = c - \Pi A$

\begin{align*}
\hat c &=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}-
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -2 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
-2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
-2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}-
\begin{pmatrix}
5 & 1 & 1 & -2 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\\
\hat c&=\begin{pmatrix}
-4 & 0 & -1 & 2 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

**Theferore $x_4$ entered the matrix. Yet, this is impossible because it already is!**

Comment: $x_4$ is a slack and hence nonnegative. I therefore do not understand how you obtained $x_4 = (\hat{b}_4)_2 = -2$. Did you make a mistake in an earlier iteration or am I missing something?

Comment: @LinAlg I obtained $\hat b_4$ from the right hand side of the constraints...

Comment: obviously your initial solution is infeasible then. You should multiply that constraint by -1 and use the two phase or big-M method to obtain a feasible starting point.

Comment: Why is it infeasible? $\{x_1=1;x_2=1\}$ respects every constraints, isn't it? Actually the  constraint was $$2x_1+x_2\ge 2\\$$ on the second line, I changed it to the one we see now...

Comment: You show that the problem is not infeasible. However, for the simplex method you need a basic feasible solution to start.

Comment: @LinAlg Understood, one different from $J_1=\{x_2;x_4;x_5\}$. Maybe I did a mistake a step above which led me to this basis?

Comment: @LinAlg Yes it is indeed infeasible as far as $J_1=\{x_2;x_4;x_5\}$ $$|A^J|=\begin{vmatrix}
-1&1&0\\
-1&0&1\\
1&0&0
\end{vmatrix}=0$$ It is therfore unfeasible.

Comment: I think $b_4 = [2; 3; 0]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for $J_0=\{x_2;x_3;x_5\}$, the determinant is
$$\begin{vmatrix}
-1&1&0\\
-1&0&0\\
1&0&1
\end{vmatrix}=-1$$ this base is feasible.

Yet, for $J_1=\{x_2;x_4;x_5\}$ $$\begin{vmatrix}
-1&1&0\\
-1&0&1\\
1&0&0
\end{vmatrix}=0$$ It is therfore unfeasible.